# ограничение движения внутреннего круга внешним

Tags: javascript, canvas

На холсте canvas отрисованы 2 окружности, одна внутри другой.
нужно ограничить движение внутренней окружности границами внешней

Comment: расстояние между центрами вы можете проверить, чтобы было не больше разницы радиусов?

Comment: @teran да, известны оба центра и оба радиуса... но что то с формулой туплю...

Comment: теорема пифагора вам в помощь

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, **в чём именно вы видите проблему**, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы нарисовать окружности у вас, очевидно, есть координаты центров `O1 (x1, y1)` и  `O2 (x2, y2)`, и их радиусы `R1` и `R2`.

Представьте, что центры ваших окружностей совпадают. На сколько вы можете сдвинуть внутреннюю окружность в сторону? на столько, на сколько различаются их радиусы. Это значит, что и центр вы можете двигать именно на такое расстояние, не больше.

Таким образом, получается, что расстояние между центрами не должно превышать `R1-R2` (или модуль этого значения).

Как посчитать расстояние между центрами, зная их координаты? В целом формулы расстояний известны. Но для наглядности, есть у вас две точки. Через одну вы проводите вертикальную линию. Через вторую - горизонтальную. Получаете прямоугольный треугольник, где гипотенуза как раз соединяет ваши точки.
Что в таком случае говорит теорема Пифагора? Что сумма квадратов длин катетов равна квадрату гипотенузы. Длины катетов каике? первый `|x2-x1|`  и второй `|y2-y1|`.

и вот чтобы корни дальше не извлекать, сравните квадрат гипотенузы с квадратом разности радиусов.

```
(x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 <= (r2-r1)^2
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, начертил посмотрел понял!!!

Answer (score 1):

В этом примере я использовал svg, для канвы формулы такие же.

Тут просто теорема Пифагора:

```
// если расстояние от центра меньше разница радиуса внешнего и внутреннего круга 
if (dx*dx + dy*dy < dr*dr)
```

А второй компонент чуть посложнее, считаем корректное положение, когда произошел выход за пределы границы, чтобы поведение было более ожидаемое и один круг не "упирался в другой".

```
// получаем из декартовых координат компонент угла полярных координат
let a = Math.atan2(dy, dx); 

// считаем центр окружности исходя из угла и возможного максимального радиуса
d3.select(this).attr("cx", x - Math.cos(a)*dr)
               .attr("cy", y - Math.sin(a)*dr);
```

---

Таскайте за внутренний круг мышкой:

```js
dragCircleInCircle('#drag1', '#bounds1');
dragCircleInCircle('#drag2', '#bounds2', true);

function dragCircleInCircle(dragCircle, boundingCircle, right){

  boundingCircle = d3.select(boundingCircle);
  dragCircle = d3.select(dragCircle).call(d3.drag().on("drag", dragged));
  
  let x = +boundingCircle.attr('cx');
  let y = +boundingCircle.attr('cy');
  let dr = +boundingCircle.attr('r') - dragCircle.attr('r');

  function dragged(d) {
    let dx = x - d3.event.x;
    let dy = y - d3.event.y;
    if (dx*dx + dy*dy < dr*dr)
      d3.select(this).attr("cx", d3.event.x)
                     .attr("cy", d3.event.y);
    else if (right) {
      let a = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
      d3.select(this).attr("cx", x - Math.cos(a)*dr)
                     .attr("cy", y - Math.sin(a)*dr);
    } 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg viewbox="0 0 200 100" height="90vh">
  <circle id="bounds1" r="40" fill="none" stroke="red" cx="50" cy="50"/>
  <circle id="drag1" r="10" fill="aqua" stroke="blue" cx="50" cy="50"/>
  <circle id="bounds2" r="40" fill="none" stroke="red" cx="150" cy="50"/>
  <circle id="drag2" r="10" fill="aqua" stroke="blue" cx="150" cy="50"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: а 50 при вычислении `dr` это что есть?

Comment: @teran omg, спасибо